# Reactjs Passing data to parent not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass selcted value from `SelectInput` to `Result` component , however I am getting an error as

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onSelectedChange is not a function
>       at SelectInput.handleChange

```
class SelectInput extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)       
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value)        
        console.log('event.target.value')        
        this.props.onSelectedChange(event.target.value) //here getting error
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <select  onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value="item1">item1</option>
                <option value="item2">item2</option>
                <option value="item3">item3</option>
            </select>
        )
    }
}

class Result extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { result: '' }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <h2>Selected :{this.state.result}</h2>
        )
    }
}
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { selected: '' }
        this.handleOnSelect = this.handleOnSelect(this)
    }
    handleOnSelect(selected) {
        console.log(selected)
        //this.setState({ selected: selected })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SelectInput onSelectedChange={this.handleOnSelect} />
                <Result />
            </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

**EDIT**

after changing the line as below, the error gone but the selected value is not passed to parent

```
 <SelectInput onSelectedChange={()=>this.handleOnSelect} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't bind in correctly in APP component do this

```
this.handleOnSelect = this.handleOnSelect.bind(this);
```

you did `this.handleOnSelect = this.handleOnSelect(this);` which is wrong

Other way is

```
<SelectInput onSelectedChange={(selected) => this.handleOnSelect(selected)} />
```

After your question edit I saw you need to pass selected argument as above.

Here is CodeSanbox working : https://codesandbox.io/s/mj6w7mv3jp

Comment: You are not recommended to do binding directly in render. BTW he already did binding in constructor and that is recommended

Comment: @Think-Twice sorry. Thank u for attendtion

Answer (score 1):

```js
class SelectInput extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)       
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value)        
        console.log('event.target.value')        
        this.props.onSelectedChange(event.target.value) //here getting error
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <select  onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value="item1">item1</option>
                <option value="item2">item2</option>
                <option value="item3">item3</option>
            </select>
        )
    }
}

class Result extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { result: '' }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <h2>Selected :{this.state.result}</h2>
        )
    }
}
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { selected: '' }
        this.handleOnSelect = this.handleOnSelect(this)
    }
    handleOnSelect(selected) {
        console.log(selected)
        //this.setState({ selected: selected })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SelectInput onSelectedChange={()=>this.handleOnSelect} />
                <Result />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <div id="root"></div>
```

You have to call function like this.

```
<SelectInput onSelectedChange={()=>this.handleOnSelect} />
```

here is full code.

```
class SelectInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log("event.target.value");
    this.props.onSelectedChange(event.target.value); //here getting error
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value="item1">item1</option>
        <option value="item2">item2</option>
        <option value="item3">item3</option>
      </select>
    );
  }
}

class Result extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { result: "" };
  }
  render() {
    return <h2>Selected :{this.state.result}</h2>;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selected: "" };
    this.handleOnSelect = this.handleOnSelect(this);
  }
  handleOnSelect(selected) {
    console.log(selected);
    //this.setState({ selected: selected })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SelectInput onSelectedChange={() => this.handleOnSelect} />
        <Result />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the error went away, but not getting the selected value in parent

Comment: console.log not getting called handleOnSelect(selected) {
        console.log(selected) in App

Comment: this.handleOnSelect = this.handleOnSelect(this) is wrong

Comment: @rashidnk even though it works for me.. check code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Update `onSelectedChange={(selected) => this.handleOnSelect(selected)}` in your App class

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { selected: '' }
        this.handleOnSelect = this.handleOnSelect(this)
    }
    handleOnSelect(selected) {
        console.log(selected)
        //this.setState({ selected: selected })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SelectInput onSelectedChange={(selected) => this.handleOnSelect(selected)} />
                <Result />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Change**
`<SelectInput onSelectedChange={this.handleOnSelect} />`

**To**
`<SelectInput onSelectedChange={() => this.handleOnSelect()} />`